# MacBook Pro runs fans at full speed constantly

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro A1278 running at 6500+ RPM all the time.

When I ran the hardware test, it showed:

> 4MOT/1/40000003: Exhaust-7358

I tried NVRAM reset, SMC reset. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your temperature sensors could be mis-reading. What do they report? You can check them with a program like [iStatMenus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/). If the readings are stuck on the max temperature the fans would stay on.

Comment: Hi, it reads 40 C in SMC fan  control. Should i install istat?

Comment: I believe that iStatMenus has a demo period, which should be long enough for you to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an app or a service running in the background, f.e. mdworker (Spotlight) hung up on indexing a file.

Have you checked with Activity Monitor.app (in /Applications/Utilities/) if there is anything taking up an unusual amount of cpu-time?

Also a quick look into the console would perhaps show some related errors. Post anything that seems out of the ordinary here.

Just to be sure: Have you installed any Software recently, like 'FanControl', 'HDD Fan Control' etc., and deleted it afterwards? I had one case in which the same symptoms appeared after an unclean uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever opened your macbook pro to clean it from dust? I have seen this symptom quite a few times, and the macs having their fans run at full-speed most of the time -especially with video playing, mostly flash on web- and the reason was that the fans and the inside of mac was full of dust.

Usually you can clean it up with compressed air, but I had success εωεν with a vacuum cleaner - just be gentle and careful.